# Is there a way to delete bones that don't have any weight assigned to them?

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

I'm trying to rig a model, but the model has upwards of 500 bones and many don't have any weight to them. I was wondering if there was a way to delete bones that aren't weighted to the mesh.

Comment: A bone might not have weight assigned to it, but still might have some effect, e.g. children.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little round-about, but if your zero-weight bones have their **deform-attribute toggled off**, there is a plugin to convert IK-Chains to FK-Chains whose side-effect is **tossing out all the non-deforming bones from the armature**.

Take a look at it here:
https://github.com/chinedufn/blender-iks-to-fks